# Android - aChartEngine getCurrentSeriesAndPoint() not working for disconnected graph

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

I am plotting the wind direction as a xyseries in a TimeChartView using aChartEngine along with windspeed (windspeed is a timeseries using left y-axis, winddir is XYSeries using right y-axis).

The problem I am facing is that as the windirection passes north, my values shift between 0 and 360, creating an ugly vertical line in my graph. I would prefer that if the values increased above 360 the graph just got clipped and resumed at 0. By filtering the values and inserting MathHelper.NULL_VALUE in my XYSeries (see code) I managed to get the graph as I wanted

```
 double windDirTemp=0;
```

...

```
    if (Math.abs(windDirValues[k] - windDirTemp)>300 ){
                windDirTemp = windDirValues[k];     
                windDirSeries.add(convertedDateinDouble[k], MathHelper.NULL_VALUE );                
            }
            else{
                windDirSeries.add(convertedDateinDouble[k], windDirValues[k]);
            }
```

The problem now is that my OnClickListener doesn't work anymore. The app crashes on

```
SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChart.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
```

I assume that inserting the null-values to my series makes getCurrentSeriesAndPoint unable to get the SeriesIndex and can have something to do with the graph no longer being connected.

I would greatly appreciate any help to solve this. Could I filter the values differently? Is there an alternative to getCurrentSeriesAndPoint() I could try?

Thanks,
Christian

EDIT:

I am using achartengine-1.1.0-rc2

My OneClickListener:

```
/**
         * Setting a click event listener for the graph
         */
        mChart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

                SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChart.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();                

                if (seriesSelection != null) {
                    int seriesIndex = seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex();
                    String selectedSeries = "Vindhastighet";
                    String unit = " m/s";

                    if (seriesIndex == 0)
                        selectedSeries = "Vindhastigheten";
                    else if (seriesIndex == 1)
                        selectedSeries = "Vindkast";
                    else {
                        selectedSeries = "Vindretningen";
                        unit = "\u00B0";
                    }

                    // Getting the clicked Date ( x value )
                    long clickedDateSeconds = (long) seriesSelection
                            .getXValue();
                    Date clickedDate = new Date(clickedDateSeconds);
                    String strDate = formatter.format(clickedDate);

                    // Getting the y value
                    int amount = (int) seriesSelection.getValue();

                    // Displaying Toast Message
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getBaseContext(),
                            selectedSeries + " kl " + strDate + " var "
                                    + amount + unit, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }                   
            }
        });
```

My logcat:

> 04-02 16:05:18.575: E/AndroidRuntime(29182): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-02 16:05:18.575: E/AndroidRuntime(29182): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   04-02 16:05:18.575: E/AndroidRuntime(29182):    at   org.achartengine.chart.XYChart.getSeriesAndPointForScreenCoordinate(XYChart.java:845)
>   04-02 16:05:18.575: E/AndroidRuntime(29182):    at org.achartengine.GraphicalView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint(GraphicalView.java:137)
>   04-02 16:05:18.575: E/AndroidRuntime(29182):    at com.example.hellogooglemaps.WindChartActivity$1.onClick(WindChartActivity.java:116)
>   04-02 16:05:18.575: E/AndroidRuntime(29182):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
>   04-02 16:05:18.575: E/AndroidRuntime(29182):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
>   04-02 16:05:18.575: E/AndroidRuntime(29182):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>   04-02 16:05:18.575: E/AndroidRuntime(29182):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   04-02 16:05:18.575: E/AndroidRuntime(29182):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   04-02 16:05:18.575: E/AndroidRuntime(29182):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
>   04-02 16:05:18.575: E/AndroidRuntime(29182):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   04-02 16:05:18.575: E/AndroidRuntime(29182):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   04-02 16:05:18.575: E/AndroidRuntime(29182):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
>   04-02 16:05:18.575: E/AndroidRuntime(29182):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
>   04-02 16:05:18.575: E/AndroidRuntime(29182):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Maybe it would help to show us your `OnClickListener`´s code and the stacktrace?

Comment: I suggest you update to the latest version: https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.1.0/

Comment: @Dan: Thanks for the latest version:) You're doing a great job! However the problem still persists and my logcat reports the same error...

Comment: Please post a small example that I can use to replicate the issue. If there is a bug, I will fix it, but I need a test case that replicates it.

Comment: @Dan thank you for pursuing this! I followed this example when I implemented the chart: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-drawing-time-chart-with-timeseries-in-achartengine/

Comment: @Dan   I have checked to confirm that if I swap the values with for example double[] visits = { 2000, 2500, MathHelper.NULL_VALUE, 2100, 2800};
     double[] views = {2200, 2700, 2900, 2800, 3200};   the app crashes with the same error report. I need to set   multiRenderer.setYAxisMin(0); multiRenderer.setYAxisMax(4000); to see the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in AChartEngine and is now fixed. You can download a version including this fix [here](https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.1.0/).

Comment: I'm still having this issue in my code. It seems to work at some points and not for others. Is it possible that it doesn't work on interpolated parts of the graph? Thanks.

Comment: Hello @Dan i have this type value. 
double[] X = { 1, 2,3 , 4 ,5}; double[] Y = {2200, MathHelper.NULL_VALUE, 2900, MathHelper.NULL_VALUE, 3200};

so here i want to draw line but skip null value where need gap and draw line between where value so what i do ?