# AChartEngine : how recognise touch in line chart?

Tags: android, achartengine

In my android app I am trying to add touch to a line chart using AChartEngine. I used this simple example:

I added a click listener to the graph

```
this.graphView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, this.graphDataset,
        this.graphRenderer);
....

this.graphView.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListenerGraph);
```

and within the buttonClickListenerGraph method I am doing this:

```
SeriesSelection seriesSelection = this.graphView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
if (seriesSelection == null) {
  Toast.makeText(this, "No chart element", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
  // display information of the clicked point
  Toast.makeText(
      this,
      "Chart element in series index " + seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex()
          + " data point index " + seriesSelection.getPointIndex() + " was clicked"
          + " closest point value X=" + seriesSelection.getXValue() + ", Y="
          + seriesSelection.getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I also enabled click

```
this.graphRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
```

where graphRenderer is XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.

But this always returns "no chart element" toast on touch. Why is it not recognising the series and line? Can someone please help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764800/android-achartengine-getcurrentseriesandpoint-not-working-for-disconnected-g

Comment: @keshav thanks! but am already using a later version of AChartengine i.e. 1.2.0. So, it should have the fix in the link you sent me. But it's still not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can control the "selectable buffer" of the clickable point, which means, the half the side of a square centered in the clicked point. AChartEngine will search over the entire square area to find a candidate for a clickable point and return the closest one.

```
mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(circleRadiusInPixels);
```